# C# any way of accessing the class name of a static class via code?

Tags: c#

Within a static class you cannot use the keyword "this" so I can't call `this.GetType().GetFullName` if I have

```
public static class My.Library.Class
{
    public static string GetName()
    {
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can call from within GetName that will return My.Library.Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the type of a predetermined class with:

```
typeof(My.Library.Class).FullName
```

If you need "the class that declares this method", you'll need to use

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName
```

However, there's a chance this method [will be inlined by the compiler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx). You can shift this call to the static constructor / initialiser of the class (which will never be inlined - log4net recommends this approach):

```
namespace My.Library

    public static class Class
    {
        static string className = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName;
        public static string GetName()
        {
             return className;
        }
    }
}
```

Applying `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` might help, but you should really [read up on that if you considering it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx)

HTH - Rob

Comment: you wasted precious seconds typing `.GetFullName()` ;)

Comment: -1 surely that's not quite right, that statement would always give "My.Library.Class"

Comment: thanks Adrian - i think i understand the question a bit better now

Comment: Yes, much, but Aen was first to answer with MethodBase.GetCurrent().etc, so still -1 :-)

Comment: @Adrian I don't really care about the points, I just want to make sure the answer is helpful (for all the other people that come to read this). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(My.Library.Class).FullName
```

Comment: good point - I forgot the part that turns a `Type` into a `string`. +1 for completeness

Answer (score 1):

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName
```